# Get valid frames from `tf2_ros.Buffer` based on `cache_time`

Tags: ros, rospy, tf2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`tf2_ros.Buffer` offers a `cache_time` argument in both C++ and Python implementations.

- [C++ doc](https://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1Buffer.html)
- [Python code](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/c73b5939723db078c9bbe18523230ad54f859682/tf2_ros/src/tf2_ros/buffer.py#L36)

However, on calling the `buffer.all_frames_as_yaml()`, the frames including those outside the cache time are included. Is there a way to clear the cache periodically or to filter the "stale" frames without having to read the YAML/string for the field: `most_recent_transform` and then convert it into a number (which also results in a loss of precision)?

PS: My understanding of `cache_time` might be wrong, so I'll rephrase my question for clarity: How do I

- Get only frames with a TF within the `cache_time` provided to the `tf2_ros.Buffer`
  OR
- Clear the expired cache of `tf2_ros.Buffer` in Python (there's a `clear` function, but like in C++, it clears the entire cache)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371825/get-valid-frames-from-%60tf2_ros.buffer%60-based-on-%60cache_time%60/) by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2021-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not a method to clear the "expired" data.  Due to there not being a clear definition of "now" at the library level the data is not evaluated compared to "now" but is compared to the lastest information heard on that topic. The cache expiration is only evaluated on insertion into that specific transform's history. This means that you'll have `cache_time` amount of history for each frame.

If you want to get the list of only frameids that have an updated data within the last X seconds I think that parsing the yaml as you're saying is likely going to be your best approach. Worrying about the precision for this seems to be a distraction compared to any useful cache duration.

A new clear method could be added to the core, however you're getting into more of the internal buffer and cache implementation and away from the specifically simple public interface for running queries.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0